# Array in PHP in an json request

Tags: php, arrays

I have this working code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.fortnox.se/3/invoices', [
'headers' => [
    'Access-Token'=>$token,
    'Client-Secret'=>$secret,
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
],
'json' => [
    "Invoice" => [
        "InvoiceRows" => [
            ["DeliveredQuantity" => "1.00","ArticleNumber" => "E0"],
            ["DeliveredQuantity" => "2.00","ArticleNumber" => "E1"]
        ],
        "CustomerNumber" => "4"
    ]
]]);
$result = $response->getBody();
```

However, I want to generate the InvoiceRows and store it as an array, But when I try to do it I getting an error sayin it is "wrong data structur". See code below..

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = ["DeliveredQuantity" => "1.00","ArticleNumber" => "E0"];
$array[1] = ["DeliveredQuantity" => "2.00","ArticleNumber" => "E1"];

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.fortnox.se/3/invoices', [
'headers' => [
    'Access-Token'=>$token,
    'Client-Secret'=>$secret,
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
],
'json' => [
    "Invoice" => [
        "InvoiceRows" => [json_encode($array)],
        "CustomerNumber" => "4"
    ]
]]);
$result = $response->getBody();
```

How should I generate this array to get the right structur? Like the working InvoiceRows on the first example?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you simply do
`"InvoiceRows" => json_encode($array)` instead of `"InvoiceRows" => [json_encode($array)]`?

Comment: I have tried that, but no luck.

Comment: why are you using json_encode?

Comment: In your previous request, you have sent a php array and in second request, you are sending json_encode.

Comment: "InvoiceRows" => $array

Comment: this is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as following :

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = ["DeliveredQuantity" => "1.00","ArticleNumber" => "E0"];
$array[1] = ["DeliveredQuantity" => "2.00","ArticleNumber" => "E1"];

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.fortnox.se/3/invoices', [
'headers' => [
    'Access-Token'=>$token,
    'Client-Secret'=>$secret,
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
],
'json' => [
    "Invoice" => [
        "InvoiceRows" => $array,
        "CustomerNumber" => "4"
    ]
]]);
$result = $response->getBody();
```

The reason your code was not working because you were passing

```
[{"DeliveredQuantity":"1.00","ArticleNumber":"E0"},{"DeliveredQuantity":"2.00","ArticleNumber":"E1"}]
```

instead of

```
[
            ["DeliveredQuantity" => "1.00","ArticleNumber" => "E0"],
            ["DeliveredQuantity" => "2.00","ArticleNumber" => "E1"]
        ]
```

Comment: Thought I tryed that! But apparently not, becase its working now. Thank you!